# tizen studio (x64) - Build Signed Package - Creating package failed - java.io.IOexception: Invalid password

Tags: java, build, tizen

I develop Tizen Wear Web app.
When I emulate it on Chrome - all is ok.

When I want to run app on device emulator or real device I see this error (screenshot):

"Build Signed Package - Creating package failed - java.io.IOexception: Invalid password": 
[ERROR PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfkl9.png)

Story:
I install tizen studio, create sertificates (like on Tizen FAQ), create new Web App from examples, try to run.. failed.

I found LOG of build, it says:
[2018.11.28 13:29:32][ERROR] TizenIncrementalSigner.java(1304) - C:\Users\USER\Desktop\tizen-studio\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-signer.p12 is invalid certificate file or password incorrect.

I want to fix this problem, but I have no ideas about what password is incorrect and how to set correct. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. See story.    What is this link? link on my question..

Comment: Install certificate manager, wearable extension and other relevant installable stuffs from package manager. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not resolved the problem yet, try this: issue a certificate from another issuer. In my case, I tried to build a package with a Samsung certificate - unsuccessfully. I managed to build the package after changing the certificate on the Tizen's one.